# Define current size of thread pool in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool, clrmd

I want to know the number of active threads (iocp and worker) in threadpool. I use this technique:

```
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out var workerAvailable, out var iocpAvailable);
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out var workerMin, out var iocpMin);
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var workerMax, out var iocpMax);

var total = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;
var workerCurrent = workerMax - workerAvailable;
var iocpCurrent = iocpMax - iocpAvailable;
var other = total - worker - iocp;
```

There are quite strange numbers in logs: 8 `worker`, 3 `iocp` and 150 `other` threads.

I made a dump using [procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) tool and inspected it using [ClrMd](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd) (`ClrThread.IsThreadpoolCompletionPort` and `ClrThread.IsThreadpoolWorker` properties). Finally I got a different result from the dump: 99 `worker` and 14 `iocp` threads.

Why does the first approach return such strange result?

**UPD:** I suppose `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` returns `max minus currently active (not idle)` threads.

Comment: More to the point, why do you need this information?

Comment: @IanKemp I'm working on application which use threads and tasks a lot. And I want to monitor how it's going internally.

Comment: The max values are pointless because these are upper limits which at least for IOCP thread are never hit. The numbers of Threadpool.GetAvailable thread are the Idle threads which wait for work. The internal state of the Threadpool is more complex. You can use ETW to track that data, or you can automate Windbg and use sos.dll to get the data you are after (see e.g. https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wmemoryprofiler how this can be done).